# Button in ItemTemplate of RadListView is losing its disabled property after PageChange

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radlistview

I have a RadListView control, which has a asp button in Itemtemplate to delete the Item . I have a requirement to make all my controls in page read only. 
Intially in Page_PreRender event
i am traversing through the all controls and their child controls and disabling them. Everything is working as expected. But when i change page of RadListView
The asp controls which i have disabled them earlier are again getting enabled. Is this expected behaviour with RadListView combining with RadPager.
Below are the properties i have set.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="ADCleintsRadAjaxManagerProxy" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ClientsRadAjaxPanel">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ClientsRadListView" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>



<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="ClientsRadAjaxPanel" runat="server" 
              LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxALoadingPanel" ViewStateMode="Disabled">

            <telerik:RadListView ID="ClientsRadListView" runat="server"
                ItemPlaceholderID="DrugsContainer" 
                AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" DataSourceID="ClientsDataSource"  
                OnItemDataBound="ClientsRadListView_OnItemDataBound"
                ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnNeedDataSource="ClientsRadListView_OnNeedDataSource"  OnItemCreated="RadListView1_ItemCreated" >
```

I have checked the Button enable property in different events when i changed the page. Below are the sequence of page flow.

**When i changed the RadListView page>**

**RadListView1_ItemCreated>** Button.enabled property is true

**PageLoad >** Button.enabled property is true

**Page_PreRender >** first disabling all the form elements with a function > I found my Button enabled property is false here after disabling means my function is working fine.

**RadListView1_ItemCreated>** This event is fired again and my button.enabled is true here.
Please can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **OnItemDataBound** event of the listview to set control properties in it.

Page_PreRender may be a tad too late and the ViewState may not get updated (which may be expected because you disabled the viewstate for the listview, so I don't know what you expect and what you are after)

Or, if you explicitly set the Enabled property to true in the ItemCreated event of the listview, this behavior is to be expected, I am not sure what exactly you are doing, the code is not provided.

Also, **replace ClientsRadAjaxPanel with an asp:Panel**. RadAjaxManager/RadAjaxManagerProxy must not ajax-enable a RadAjaxPanel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. finally got one reply after 7days. What we are trying to do is making the entire application read only based on condition. I wrote a global method to disable all web controls as well telerik controls in a overridden page_preRender method. I m able to make all web controls read only except this RadGrid/ Radlistview(When page changed). All server controls in RadGrid/RadList view are losing their properties after pagination.

Comment: According to [http://www.telerik.com/forums/selection-style-lost-when-paging](telerik) it is expected behaviour when rebinding. If i approach using "OnItemDataBound" i have to edit all pages which have RadGrid/RadListview. Instead i am looking for global solution to it.

Comment: You could try implementing a recursive control tree traversal so all controls on the page would be disabled, but you would need to call it with each postback.

Comment: On second thought, why not just add a transparent <div> over the viewport to consume clicks and keyboard events? In all cases you must validate inputs because even with Enabled=false a POST can be generated, so you need to stop the client interaction, and you can do that with a few bits of HTML, CSS and JS

Comment: i used recursive control to disable elements in page_preRender. It is working fine as expected when i load a page. But controls in rad list view are messing up once i do the paging. they gets enabled from nowhere. I had a thought to showing a invisible layer all over page , but u know security reasons it can be edited in console and also user can not click on next page if a invisible layer is there

Comment: try enabling the ViewState to see if it will help you retain server properties

Also, a POST can be generated for disabled inputs as well. You can put buttons over the overlay.